# OpenGL ES 2.0 colour subtraction

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es-2.0

with

```
glBlend(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
```

I can make pixel 2 times darker by multiplying on alpha (0.5)

But what should I do if I wish to subtract color

e.g. `red - 0.1` instead of `red * 0.9`

It seems shader is unable to produce negative colors.
I do not wish to render in float point texture's render buffer.
It is too expensive. App will run slow. It will not work on all most phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot specifically tell, not gripped up much in OpenGL but, still from what I can help, I'll do.

If I understand correctly, you need a value within 0 to 1 inclusive-float to subtract from an already existing colour component's value.

For this, visit this link : http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php

It can help you will live checking of blending between two images.

Check for the blend function : GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT

Comment: You definitely a winner :) I waited because `GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT` seems to be poorly supported. I am not sure if I can rely on it without testing or most platforms. Too many reports that `GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

One issue to be aware of is you can't use GLUtils.texImage2D() to load alpha textures on Android. This is a common problem that Google really should document better. The problem is that the Bitmap class converts all images into pre-multiplied format, but that does not work with OpenGL ES unless the image is completely opaque. The best solution is to use native code. This article gives more detail on this:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Comment: I will not minus. But I do not understand how Java/Android issue relates to my OpenGL ES blend question. If I can add texture BUT can't subtract then Alpha is not problem. And yes. I use native code and load texture myself from PVR file on both iOS and Android.

Comment: It sounds like you are bypassing the Bitmap class, so this is not an issue.